# Where to place a class with utility methods in zf2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using zend framework 2.x and I am wondering where to place a utility-class? It is neither a controller nor an entity?! In Java I would have created a package utilities right under the source folder main program package.

Comment: You usually just create a module that contains your common files.

Answer (score 0):

1- service for common use of languages (accessible in controller,actions,views) 
2- "view helper" or "place holder" for phtml file (view scripts)

in view helper you can access db for example MenuHelper . i suggest different solution for different place .

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'commentRepository' => function ($sm) {
                $em = $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
                $comment_repository = $em->getRepository('Comment\Entity\Comment');
                return $comment_repository;
            },
            'commentService' => function ($sm) {
                $comment_service = new Service\CommentService();
                $comment_service->setRepository($sm->get('commentRepository'));
                return $comment_service;
            }
        ),
    );
}

public function getViewHelperConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'commentList' => function ($helpers) {
                $locator = $helpers->getServiceLocator();
                $viewHelper = new View\Helper\CommentList();
                $viewHelper->setCommentService($locator->get('commentService'));
                return $viewHelper;
            },
        )
    );
}
```

do you want to use it in certain places ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a folder at the same level of my controller directory:

```
src/ModuleNameSpace/Controller
src/ModuleNameSpace/Utilities
```

However if the code will be shared across modules in your application, you should create a common module or place the files in the application module at the same level